# No error returned in my printf wrapper using varargs

Tags: c, variadic-functions, stdio

I've recently gotten back into working with C, and I decided to write a library as a wrapper for stdio.h. The goal is to do all the error checking possible so that the user won't have to do it themselves whenever they call a stdio function. This is partly for learning, and partly for real use (since I frequently use stdio).

When I write the following (in main), gcc gives an error at compile time, since there is supposed to be an integer as another argument but none was passed.

```
printf("Your integer: %d\n");
```

In case it's useful, here are my compiler flags:

```
-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Here's part of my current wrapper function. It works perfectly and checks for quite a few errors when passed valid/correct arguments:

```
uintmax_t gsh_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int cnt;
    va_start(arg, format);
    cnt = vprintf(format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    // Analyze cnt and check for stream errors here
    return (uintmax_t)cnt;
}
```

But here's the problem, if I call:

```
gsh_printf("Your integer: %d\n");
```

It does *not* give an error, and it even runs! The usual output is something like:

```
Your integer: 1799713
```

Or some other number, implying that it's accessing memory not allocated to it, but it never gives a segmentation fault either.

So, why does it not give an error of any kind? And how can I write my own code so that there is a compile-time error, or at least run-time error after checking types, number of args, etc.?

Of course, any help is greatly appreciated, and if you need any more information, just let me know. Thank you!

Comment: look at the header where printf is defined, it must have some sort of annotation so the compiler knows to treat it as a format string

Comment: I checked before, but there's no hint in stdio.h, just a reasonably normal function declaration. I can't find a stdio.c file, so I assume it _may_ have been written in another language or precompiled or something.

Comment: It's syntactically legal to pass printf() a "%d" without adding additional arguments (since printf() uses C's variable arguments).  The reason the compiler complains is because it is programmed to do so.  It tries its best to notice that this is likely a semantic issue that would "never" be intended, so it throws a warning/error.  The data being displayed is "garbage".  The reason it does not throw a segmentation fault is likely because its interpreting a prior stack value as the missing int argument.  Unless you go over a page or some other OS error, you probably won't see a fault.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Are you saying that printf is not required (by the standard) to check for the proper number of arguments? If that's the case, I can live with the user being forced to check their own printfs, though it'd of course be nicer to check them for them.

Comment: Yes.  Technically it is "undefined behavior" for the function.  But most compilers can (and will) detect this.  EDIT: Printf() uses the format string to detect the number of arguments (rather than passing the number as an additional parameter or anything of the like.)  The function "assumes" the format string to be correct and it is up to the user (or a good compiler) to ensure that this is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `fprintf` and `fscanf` families of functions, if a conversion specification corresponding argument is missing, the function call invokes undefined behavior.

With `gcc` use *format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)* function attribute to request a diagnostic:

```
extern uintmax_t gsh_printf(const char *format, ...)
    __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));

uintmax_t gsh_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    int cnt;
    va_start(arg, format);
    cnt = vprintf(format, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    // Analyze cnt and check for stream errors here
    return (uintmax_t)cnt;
}
```

See documentation for an explanation of *archetype*, *string-index* and *first-to-check*:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

For example with the example above, with `-Wall` (because of `-Wformat`), with this statement:

```
gsh_printf("Your integer: %d\n");
```

you'll get this warning:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat]

With `-Wall` (because of `-Wformat-extra-args`) you will also get a warning for extra arguments:

```
gsh_printf("Your integer: %d\n", 0, 1);
```

gives

> warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Comment: I've tried it out, and it works perfectly! I wish it was standard, but it's a nice, clean solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no way to determine whether or not the number of arguments that are passed when using va_list is the amount of arguments required. In the C calling convention the arguments are pushed onto the stack starting from the right-most argument. The way printf works is it parses the format string and pops a value from the stack whenever needed. Thus you get the random number when calling

`gsh_printf("Your integer: %d\n");`

You would need to know in advance how many arguments are supplied which cannot be done using va_list.

You might be able to get around this by using some kind of container class to hold all the arguments and use the number of elements in the container to check if there are enough.

Also notice that 'args' is just a pointer to the start of the argument list. So when you pass it to vprintf, vprintf just prints the value of the pointer.

Comment: Interesting idea. Part of my goal was to keep the function arguments identical to the standard ones for backward compatibility, but it's worth considering.